# Azure IoT RegistryManager, block reusing certificates

Tags: c#, azure, iot

I'm trying to find if its possible using RegistryManager to have it not register a device if the thumbprint of the certificate is already in use on another device.

```
_registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(_connectionString);
            Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Device device;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Registering Device using X.509 certificate for authentication");
                device = await _registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Device(deviceId)
                {
                    Authentication = new AuthenticationMechanism()
                    {
                        X509Thumbprint = new X509Thumbprint()
                        {
                            PrimaryThumbprint = certificate2.Thumbprint
                        }
                    }
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
```

So if that code above was called and another device had that thumbprint, I want it to fail. Alternatively I want to be able to view all existing thumbprints so i can manually check before registering.

I can't see any way to do this via RegistryManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alternatively I want to be able to view all existing thumbprints so i
>   can manually check before registering.

You can get existing thumbprints like this:

```
        var _registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(_connectionString);
        var devices = await _registryManager.GetDevicesAsync(100); //Here I use 100 for testing purpose. Replace this value with yours.
        foreach (var dev in devices)
        {
            if (dev.Authentication.X509Thumbprint.IsValid(false))
            {
                var primaryThumbprint = dev.Authentication.X509Thumbprint.PrimaryThumbprint;
                var secondaryThumbprint = dev.Authentication.X509Thumbprint.SecondaryThumbprint;
                Console.WriteLine("primaryThumbprint:" + primaryThumbprint);
                Console.WriteLine("SecondaryThumbprint:" + SecondaryThumbprint);
            }
        }
```